# 録音を行う処理のObjective-CからSwiftへの書き換え方法が分からない

Tags: swift

現在、音声録音を行っているのですが以下の書き換えがわかりません。
もし教えていただける方がいらっしゃいましたらご指導の程よろしくお願いいたします。

```
// 使用している機種が録音に対応しているか
if ([audioSession inputIsAvailable]) {
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
}
if error {
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [error domain], [error code], [[error userInfo] description]);
}
```

Comment: Appleのドキュメント

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setCategory:withOptions:error:

に該当メソッドのObj-C版とSwift版が掲載されていると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。関連している部分は参考にしてみようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？
（Xcode 7.0.1で確認）

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

// inputIsAvailableは廃止になったのでinputAvailableを使用
if audioSession.inputAvailable {

    // Swift2でNSErrorの扱いがdo/try/catchに変更された
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

    } catch let err {

        // Swift2ではNSLogではなくprintを使用
        print("audioSession: \(err)")
    }
}
```

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。私が試してみたところ、
if audioSession.inputAvailable {
この部分でエラーが出てしまいます。これはバージョンアップが原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: 使用しているXcodeのバージョンと、エラーの詳細はわかりますか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません解決することができました！
丁寧なご指導ありがとうございました！